# Вывод в цикле for или foreach php

Tags: php, циклы

Добрый день. У меня есть массив с данными $products.

Мне необходимо чтобы вывод формировался так:

```
<div class="lof-main-item page-**1**" style="left: 0px; width: 716px; display: block;">

<foreach($products as $product):?>
   <div class="lof-row" style="width:24.9%">
    ...
   </div> 
<?endforeach?>

<foreach($products as $product):?>
   <div class="lof-row" style="width:24.9%">
    ...
   </div> 
<?endforeach?>

<foreach($products as $product):?>
   <div class="lof-row" style="width:24.9%">
    ...
   </div> 
<?endforeach?>

</div>

<div class="lof-main-item page-**2**" style="left: 0px; width: 716px; display: block;">

 <foreach($products as $product):?>
   <div class="lof-row" style="width:24.9%">
    ...
   </div> 
<?endforeach?>

 <foreach($products as $product):?>
   <div class="lof-row" style="width:24.9%">
    ...
   </div> 
<?endforeach?>

<foreach($products as $product):?>
   <div class="lof-row" style="width:24.9%">
    ...
   </div> 
<?endforeach?>

</div>
```

Т.е. по сути мне необходимо чтобы в теле:

```
<div class="lof-main-item page-**1**" style="left: 0px; width: 716px; display: block;">
</div>
```

происходил перебор массива $product максимум 4-х элементов. А после того, как 4 элемента foreach обошёл - надо поменять это:

```
<div class="lof-main-item page-**1**" style="left: 0px; width: 716px; display: block;">
</div>
```

на это:

```
<div class="lof-main-item page-**2**" style="left: 0px; width: 716px; display: block;">
</div>
```

Как мне это реализовать? Очень прошу помощи...

Comment: ничего не понятно)  
количество `page-**1**` известно?    
выводить $products 3 раза по 4 элемента??  
я даже сокровенный смысл этого не понял :)))

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php foreach (array_chunk($products, 4) as $idx => $chunk): ?>

<div class="lof-main-item page-<?=($idx + 1)?>" style="left: 0px; width: 716px; display: block;">

    <?php foreach ($chunk as $product): ?>

    <div class="lof-row" style="width:24.9%">
    ...
    </div>

    <?php endforeach ?>

</div>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($product as $val){
    echo <<<LABEL
<div class="lof-main-item page-$val" style="left: 0px; width: 716px; display: block;">

<foreach($products as $product):?> <div class="lof-row" style="width:24.9%"> ... </div> <?endforeach?>

<foreach($products as $product):?> <div class="lof-row" style="width:24.9%"> ... </div> <?endforeach?>

<foreach($products as $product):?> <div class="lof-row" style="width:24.9%"> ... </div> <?endforeach?>

</div>

LABEL;
}
```

Это еще при условии что я вас правильно понял))

Comment: Нет, Вы меня не правильно поняли=)

Comment: я тоже не понял что тут спрашивается. Даже удивился, что кто то понял и отвечает.

Answer (score 0):

я бы использовал for, а проверял бы в каждом цикле так:

```
    $count = count($products);
    $c = $count-1;

for($i=0;$count>$i;$i++){

if($c == $i){

echo '<div class="lof-main-item page-**2**" style="left: 0px; width: 716px; display: block;">
</div>';

}
```